# Is there a binding for an MvvmCross MvxSpinner for the OnItemSelected event?

Tags: android, spinner, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an MvxSpinner defined as below and I'm trying to trigger a command when the user chooses an item in the spinner via the `ItemSelected` binding:

```
    <Mvx.MvxSpinner
        style="@style/Spinners"
        android:id="@+id/jobStatusSpinner"
        android:prompt="@string/jobstatus_prompt"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource JobStatuses; SelectedItem SelectedJobStatus; ItemSelected FilterJobsByStatusCommand"
        local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/spinner_jobstatuses"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_jobstatus" />
```

I've confirmed that the `FilterJobsByStatusCommand` can be called from the view by adding a button:

```
<Button
    android:text="Test"
    android:background="@drawable/StandardButton"
    style="@style/Buttons.FullWidth"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    local:MvxBind="Click FilterJobsByStatusCommand" />
```

This successfully triggers the `FilterJobsByStatusCommand` which also successfully uses the `SelectedJobStatus` property of the ViewModel to update the list of jobs. Should the  `ItemSelected` binding work or am I missing some other code or a different binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ItemSelected` is a `EventHandler<ItemSelectedEventArgs>` so it can't be bound to without a custom binding.

To create a custom binding, see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n28-custom-bindings-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html

For a simple event-to-command binding, then you can probably base your customer binding on something like: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxViewLongClickBinding.cs - e.g. something like:

```
public class SpinnerItemSelectedBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    private ICommand _command;

    protected MvxSpinner View
    {
        get { return (MvxSpinner) Target; }
    }

    public SpinnerItemSelectedBinding (MvxSpinner view)
        : base(view)
    {
        view.ItemSelected += ViewOnItemSelected;
    }

    private void ViewOnItemSelected(object sender, ItemSelectedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_command == null)
            return;

        if (!_command.CanExecute(null))
            return;

        _command.Execute(null);
    }

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        _command = value as ICommand;
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof (ICommand); }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            var view = View;
            if (view != null)
            {
                view.ItemSelected -= ViewOnItemSelected;
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }
}
```

which you could register in your setup as:

```
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<MvxSpinner>("ItemSelected",
                                                        view =>
                                                        new SpinnerItemSelectedBinding (view));
```

---

If it helps, there's some background to a recent attempt to get auto-binding to TEventArgs events working on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/313

---

If your app can cope with just a bound value instead of a bound event/command, then the `SelectedItem` binding works for me in the N+1 video I recorded last night - http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/07/n35-multibinding-with-tibet-n1-videos.html - with source at https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-35-Tibet/BindMe.Droid/Resources/Layout/FirstView.axml#L17

`SelectedItem` is also used in the `ApiExamples` sample project: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Droid/Resources/Layout/Test_Spinner.axml

Answer (score 13):

Try to bind on `HandleItemSelected` property.
It's attempt an `ICommand` value.

```
<Mvx.MvxSpinner
        style="@style/Spinners"
        android:id="@+id/jobStatusSpinner"
        android:prompt="@string/jobstatus_prompt"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource JobStatuses; SelectedItem SelectedJobStatus; HandleItemSelected FilterJobsByStatusCommand"
        local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/spinner_jobstatuses"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_jobstatus" />
```

Comment: This solution works perfect! I wish i could give it 10 up-vote

Comment: You can use a command with parameter: `MvxAsyncCommand<T> handleYearSelectedCommand` (T is the selected item's type).

Comment: Its working fine, however the item for 0th index got overriding 'HandleItemSelected' and it is perhaps wrong.? any idea?

Comment: Sorry to bring this back from the dead, but has anyone tried this with version 6.4.1.. I've been trying to get a spinner to work, and this SelectedItem, or even the HandleItemSelected commands now do not work i believe.